# How to create view with subquery in from cluse - Maria DB

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

hy, I am trying to create a view but get the following error:

> 1349-View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause

i use server version **10.0.12-MariaDB**

how should *i change my query*

this is my query :

```
SELECT Q1.NIK, Q1.Enroll
FROM
emp0003,
(SELECT dvc0005.NIK, dvc0005.Enroll FROM dvc0005 UNION DISTINCT SELECT dvc0004.NIK, dvc0004.Enroll FROM dvc0004) AS Q1
WHERE 
    Emp0003.IsActive = 'T' 
    AND YEAR(DATE(Q1.Enroll))=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) 
    AND emp0003.NIK=Q1.NIK
```

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you can express this using `union` between two subqueries:

```
SELECT d.NIK, d.Enroll
FROM dvc0005 d
WHERE YEAR(DATE(d.Enroll)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM emp0003 e
              WHERE e.NIK = d.NIK AND e.IsActive = 'T' 
             )
UNION
SELECT d.NIK, d.Enroll
FROM dvc0004 d
WHERE YEAR(DATE(d.Enroll)) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM emp0003 e
              WHERE e.NIK = d.NIK AND e.IsActive = 'T' 
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not have subquery in from clause  to create a view. Either you need to write it in another way avoiding subquery or you can use multiple view.

First create a view named Q1 for the subquery:

```
create view Q1 as SELECT dvc0005.NIK, dvc0005.Enroll FROM dvc0005 UNION DISTINCT SELECT dvc0004.NIK, dvc0004.Enroll FROM dvc0004
```

Then user this view in your actual query to create a new view:

```
SELECT Q1.NIK, Q1.Enroll
FROM
emp0003,
 Q1
WHERE 
    Emp0003.IsActive = 'T' 
    AND YEAR(DATE(Q1.Enroll))=YEAR(CURRENT_DATE) 
    AND emp0003.NIK=Q1.NIK
```